# cloudant nosql db query with regex

Tags: regex, cloudant

I have a cloudant nosql db with some records like this:

```
{
 "role": "utente",
 "nome": "Rocco",
 "cognome": "Di Vitto",
 "team": "sap pm-cs",
 "company": "wrestling",
 "appManager": "john Ford",
 "teamLeader": "Rendy Orton, Colombo M.R."
}
```

I would like to query my db with a $regex the teamLeader field, passing a single string that matches either with "Randy Orton" or "Colombo M.R." but I can't figure out the regex for matching two comma-delimited strings. I've tried reading Erlang queries structure but I didn't find the solution. Some help would be very useful. thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/8OjOkW/1)

Comment: Not seeing the `perl` in this question.

Comment: i composed this query

{
   "selector": {

      "teamLeader": {
        "$.+(?|(Colombo M\.R\.)|(Rendy Orton)).+" : "Randy Orton"
      }
   }
}

but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when supplying regular expressions you should be using the [$regex](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#the-regex-operator) operator. have you tried something like this:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "teamLeader": {
         "$regex": "(Colombo M.R.)|(Rendy Orton)"
      }
   }
}
```